# Array inside subscribe() is empty when trying to use forEach() or map() outside service, but filled in service

Tags: angular, graphql, subscribe

I am trying to access strings from a string array that come back from an observable. When I am trying to do so from inside my service with the following code, all goes well. (the `getAll()` method returns data from a graphQL query)

```
private tags: Observable<any>;

getTags() : Observable<string[]> {
    if (!this.tags)
    {
      var tagsSource = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>(null);
      this.tags = tagsSource.asObservable();

      var tags : string[] = [];
      this.getAll().subscribe(result => {
        result.data.all.forEach(item =>{
          if(item.tags !== null && item.tags !== undefined)
          {
            item.tags.forEach(tag => {
              if(!tag.includes("["))
              {
                if(!tags.includes(tag))
                {
                  tags.push(tag);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
      })
      tagsSource.next(tags);
    }
    return this.tags;
  }
```

this code returns an observable of strings. When I subscribe to this observable outside the service, I can no longer access each string individually inside the `subscribe` method. I have the following code:

```
this.myService.getTags().subscribe(tags => {
  console.log(tags)
  console.log(tags.length)
  this.tags = tags.forEach(tag => {
    console.log(tag)
  });
})
```

the tags in the console is a filled array, but the length comes back as 0. The individual tags are also never logged.

What I want is access each string in the array so I can convert it to a custom object. 
What am I missing?

Comment: *this code returns an observable of strings*: no, it doesn't return anything. And if it had a return statement, it would return a Subscription, not an Observable. It's also unclear if that code is the body of myService.getTags() or something else, and what the myService.getTags() method actually does. Post the relevant, compiling code.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I missed part of the getTags function. I added it.

Comment: Please provide a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).